# How to loop through dates in django

Tags: django

Does anyone knows as to how to loop through dates in Django. I have a code here which does not loop :-

```
for dt in range(date1,date2):
    print(dt.dateTime())
```

Comment: Not nearly enough information. What are `date1` and `date2` here? What do you see when you run this?

Comment: @Sanchit What are you expecting the outputs of the loop to be? What are you currently getting?

Answer (score 1):

You can itterate loop over dates using `step = datetime.timedelta(1)`

```
import datetime
date1 = datetime.date(2007, 12, 5)
date2 = datetime.date(2007, 12, 12)
step = datetime.timedelta(1)
curr = date1
while curr < date2:
    print curr
    curr += step
```